# Xamarin call c# model method from razor cshtml input

Tags: c#, html, razor, xamarin

I'm building an app in Xamarin which will display a webview allowing the users to select a platform to authenticate with using OAuth. In the webview an image of the OAuth provides is displayed which, when clicked should call a method on the model which will handle the OAuth for the that platform. I can't seem to find out now to call the function on the model from the onclick event of the image.

cshtml:

```html
@model OAuthLogin
<html>
    <body>
         <input id="button" type="image" src="@Model.ImageFile" onclick="login()"/>
    </body>
    <script>
        function login() {
            alert("Model.OpenAuthenticator() should be called from here...");
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

model:

```
public class OAuthLogin {
    public string ImageFile => ImageString();
    private SupportedPlatform Platform { get; }
    private const string GoogleImage = "Images/google.svg";
    private const string MicrosoftImage = "Images/microsoft.svg";

    public OAuthLogin(SupportedPlatform platform) {
        Platform = platform;
    }

    public void OpenAuthenticator() =>
        Authenticator.Authenticate(Platform);

    private string ImageString() {
        switch (Platform) {
            case SupportedPlatform.Google: {
                return GoogleImage;
            }
            case SupportedPlatform.Microsoft: {
                return MicrosoftImage;
            }
            default: {
                throw new NotSupportedException($"No authentication implemented for platform {Platform}.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try with something like @Model.OpenAuthenticator() ?

Comment: Yes, what this seems to do is call the OpenAuthenricator() method when the html is contructed and put its return value as a string into the html.

Comment: Yes, you can only call a server-side function while still at the server. Once the view is rendered, you'd need to call the function through a Controller action

Comment: There is no server involved here since this cshtml is embedded into the application? Assuming this works the same way, how would I call the authenticator through a "controller action"?

Comment: what are you using XForms or Classic? What platform(s) you need this on?

Comment: The app is build in Xamarin Forms for Android and iOS, and needs to be able to be extended to WinPhone in future.